# Android AndEngine GameNot Running

Tags: java, android, andengine

i am new in android gaming and i am using andEngine for making android games i have just made a sample using andEngine but the problem is when i run my application on emulator the application not run i dont know why even i have enabled GPU emulation on emulator but my aplpication not working.

i have made .apk file to install game in real device but still the same problem Application not run gives error. Help me to solve the issue

my Code and i am using android API 2.3.3

```
package com.game.practice;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;

public class GamePracticeActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================
    static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Camera mCamera;
    private Scene mMainScene;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger()); // logs the frame rate

        /* Create Scene and set background colour to (1, 1, 1) = white */
        this.mMainScene = new Scene();
        this.mMainScene.setBackground(new Background(1, 1, 1));

        return this.mMainScene;
    }

}
```

LogCat Errors

[image: These are the errors i am recieving when i run the application On Emulators]

Comment: what should i post from Log cat?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a ClassNotFoundException. There are only a few reasons you will ever get this error:

1. The class genuinely doesn't exist. If you are using code from an official example and getting this, make sure you have the latest build of the library
2. You have not added the andengine jar to your build path. To fix this, right click on the jar in Eclipse, and do Build Path ► Add to Build Path.
3. Your andengine jar is not in the /libs folder. This happens when you have added the jar to the build path, but newer versions of ADT need it to be in /libs. Put it there and re-add it to the build path.
4. Make sure you have declared the class in the correct package, and have given a corresponding full qualified name in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: when i add anEngine library in my project it automatically create AndroidDependencies folder and put the jar there. please tell me how can i make lib folder and put my jar file there

Comment: Create a libs folder in the root of your project. Add the jar to it. Add that jar to the build path.

Comment: can u please tell me how to set the build path?

Comment: i have done what you said i made a folder calld lib and copy the jar there and then set the build path but when i set the build path the folder is created Called RefrencedLibraries but still my application is not working

Comment: The folder must be called libs. With an "s".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the last vesion of Andengine? The one from github? [AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine)

Note: AndEngine has to be build with ADT-17 or higher!

If you import the project from github to eclipse, you don't need to do all those steps of the libs folder, you just need to define dependency between projects and Eclipse will do the rest for you.

PD: have you declared GamePracticeActivity in your manifest?

edit:

In order to make Eclipse work with Github you need a plug-in. I use [EGIT](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/). It is really easy to use. Here you can find a topic at Andengine's forum where the author of Andengine talks about it. [LINK](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/use-andengine-as-a-android-library-project-not-as-a-jar-t6142.html)

Comment: i have downloaded the latest version from github and made the jars and then i used that. For you information i have downloaded the latest eclipse but there is no github option for clonning the project i dont know why i tried to update eclipse and i found the github link but that link doesn't work please help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add permission for andengine project. The following line work for you.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```